# AngularJS Custom Validation Directives - How to avoid using isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-model

I'm attempting to use multiple angular validators on a text field, but have run into the `Multiple directives requesting isolated scope` error. (Please read on before closing as a duplicate.)

All the solutions I've seen so far, recommend removing the `scope: {...}` from the offending directives, however for my scenario, I need to evaluate variables from the controller (and `$watch` them for changes).

I've tried using `attrs.$observe`, but I can't work out how to get the **evaluated variables** into the `$validator` function. (Additionally, I can't `$observe` the `ngModel`).

Please let me know if there's a another way to solve this issue.

Here's the smallest example I could put together. **N.B.** `maxLength` validator's scope is commented out, essentially disabling it:

```js
angular

.module('app', [])

// validates the min length of a string...
.directive("minLen", function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: {
        ngModel: '=',
        minLen: '='
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        scope.$watch('ngModel', function(){
          ngModelCtrl.$validate();
        });
        scope.$watch('minLen', function(){
          ngModelCtrl.$validate();
        });
        ngModelCtrl.$validators.minLength = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
          var value = modelValue || viewValue;
          return angular.isUndefined(scope.minLen) ||
            angular.isUndefined(value) ||
            value.length >= scope.minLen;
        };
      }
 };
})

.directive("maxLen", function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
// Commented out for now - causes error.      
//       scope: {
//         ngModel: '=',
//         maxLen: "="
//       },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        scope.$watch('ngModel', function(){
          ngModelCtrl.$validate();
        });
        scope.$watch('maxLen', function(){
          ngModelCtrl.$validate();
        });
        ngModelCtrl.$validators.maxLength = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
          var value = modelValue || viewValue;
          return angular.isUndefined(scope.maxLen) ||
            angular.isUndefined(value) ||
            value.length >= scope.maxLen;
        };
      }
 };
})

// this controller just initialises variables...
.controller('CustomController', function() {
  var vm = this;
  vm.toggleText = function(){
    if (vm.text === 'aaa') {
      vm.text = 'bbbbb';
    } else {
      vm.text = 'aaa';
    }
  }
  vm.toggle = function(){
    if (vm.minLen === 3) {
      vm.minLen = 4;
      vm.maxLen = 12;
    } else {
      vm.minLen = 3;
      vm.maxLen = 10;
    }
  };
  vm.toggleText();
  vm.toggle();
  return vm;
})
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="CustomController as ctrl">
  <ng-form name="ctrl.form">
    <label>Enter {{ctrl.minLen}}-{{ctrl.maxLen}} characters: </label>
    <input 
           name="text" 
           type="text" 
           ng-model="ctrl.text" 
           min-len="ctrl.minLen"
           max-len="ctrl.maxLen"
           />
  </ng-form>
  <br/><br/>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.toggle()">Modify validation lengths</button>
  <button ng-click="ctrl.toggleText()">Modify ngModel (text)</button>
  
  <h3>Validation (just list $error for now)</h3>
  <pre>{{ ctrl.form.text.$error | json }}</pre>
</div>
```

Comment: Why are you not using [ng-maxlength](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMaxlength) and [ng-minlength](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMinlength) directives?

Comment: @georgeawg - because I've tried to boil this down to the simplest example. My real example is "deep" validating an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

Remove isolate scope and use [scope.$watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) to evaluate the attribute:

```
app.directive("minLen", function() {
    return {
      require: 'ngModel',
      restrict: 'A',
      scope: false,
   //     ngModel: '=',
   //     minLen: '='
   //   },
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
        var minLen = 0;
        scope.$watch(attrs.minLen, function(value){
          minLen = toInt(value) || 0;
          ngModelCtrl.$validate();
        });
        ngModelCtrl.$validators.minLength = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
          return ngModelCtrl.$isEmpty(viewValue) || viewValue.length >= minLen;
        };
      }
    };
})
```

There is no need to watch the `ngModel` attribute as the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) will automatically invoke the functions in the [$validators](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#$validators) collection when the model changes.

When the watch expression is a string, the string attribute will be evaluated as an [Angular Expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression).

For more information, see [AngularJS scope API Reference - $watch](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch).

Answer (score 0):

1. remove isolated scope
2. You dont need to observe, watch ngModel - when it changes, angular will run validator for you.
3. Decide how you want to use your directive: my-val-dir="{{valName}}" vs my-val-dir="valName". In first case you use attrs.$observe('myValDir'), in second $watch(attrs.myValDir) & $eval. 
   When your value gonna be something simple, like number or short string - first way seems good, when value is something big, i.e. array - use second approach.